# Elements of $A_8$ commuting with $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

How would we go about showing that in $A_8$, an element of order $3$ commuting with a subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$ is necessarily a $3$-cycle?

I know that an element of order $3$ in $A_8$ must be a product of disjoint $3$-cycles, and therefore can be either a $3$ cycle or a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles.

Comment: "a subgroup isomorphic with a subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$" is redundant; it refers to exactly the subgroups that "a subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$" refers to.

Comment: @joriki Apologies, that was a typo. The question has been edited.

Comment: Do you not find it clear that the element $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ of $S_8$ does not commute with any element of order $5$ in $S_8$?

Answer (score 1):

$A_5$ contains $20$ elements of order $3$. Given a disjoint product of two 3-cycles, you simply cannot find a set of $20$ elements of order $3$ in $A_8$ that commute with it. So finding a whole subgroup isomorphic to $A_5$ that commutes with said element is also necessarily impossible.

Comment: Could you explain why we cannot find such a set in $A_8$?

Comment: @BulkyMolaMola Try. How many order 3 elements can you find that commute with $(123)(456)$?